# Cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'qlonglong' (aka 'long long')

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtconcurrent, qfuture

I get this error while trying to use `QtConcurrent`:

> Cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'qlonglong' (aka 'long long')

I'm trying to compute the size of a folder. I made a method that returns the size, which is of type `qlonglong`. I want to run this method in another thread, which is `QtConcurrent`, but I get the error.

```
QFuture<qlonglong> future = QtConcurrent::run(this,&backD::analysa());
```

Comment: Looks like you want to pass in ta pointer to the method `backD::analysa`, but the brackets on the end of `&backD::analysa()` invoke the method instead. Remove the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to *call* `analysa()` and then take the address of its return value.  You need to instead take the address of `analysa` itself. To do that, simply remove the parenthesis from it:

```
QFuture<qlonglong> future = QtConcurrent::run(this,&backD::analysa);
```